# Show that $\det(xA+(1-x)B)=0$ for only finitely many values of $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

> Show that $$\det(xA+(1-x)B) = 0$$ for only finitely many values of $x$ where $A,B$  are $n \times n$ real invertible matrices.

Consider $$f(x)=\det(xA+(1-x)B)$$

Obviously, $f(1),f(0)\neq 0$. Hence, $f \equiv 0$ is false. But, how to show that it is zero for finitely many $x$?

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $f(0) = f(1)$.

Comment: $\det (xA + (1-x)B)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree at most $n.$

Comment: @Join_PhD are you a PhD student?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** The quantity $\det[x A + (1 - x) B]$ is a polynomial in $x$, and, as you've observed, it is not identically zero.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $:$ $\det (xA + (1-x)B)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree at most $n.$

Comment: How is $\det(xA+(1-x)B) $ a polynomial of degree at most $n$

Comment: Try to do it by induction on $n.$ Observe that each entry of $xA+(1-x)B$ is a linear function in $x.$ Try to recall how to expand determinant w.r.t. one of it's row let's say first row.

Comment: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} &a_{22}\end{bmatrix},B=\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12}\\b_{21} &b_{22} \end{bmatrix}$  then $Ax+(1-B)x=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} x+(1-x)b_{11}& a_{12}x+(1-x)b_{12}\\a_{21}x +(1-x)b_{21}& a_{22}x+(1-x)b_{22}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Now $\det\{(Ax)+(1-x)B\}=\{ a_{11} x+(1-x)b_{11}\}\times \{a_{21}x +(1-x)b_{21}\}-\{a_{22}x+(1-x)b_{22}\}\{ a_{12}x+(1-x)b_{12}\}$

Comment: @Join_PhD;Now notice that it is a quadratic polynomial in $x$.Similarly if you take an $n$ degree matrix it is an $n-$ degree polynomial,If you have any more doubts,please dont hesitate to ask

Comment: @Learnmore,No,its clear now ,thank you very much sir